# RSA Decryption C# The data to be decrypted exceeds the maximum for this modulus of 256 bytes

Tags: c#, winforms, encryption, cryptography, rsa

I was trying to decrypt the encrypted data which was in string format, because of this i have to execute the Encoding function 2 times which leads me to this error The data to be decrypted exceeds the maximum for this modulus of 256 bytes. However if i pass in the encrypted data in bytes format, the decryption works.

Here is the issue, i want user to copy and paste the encrypted data into a Textbox(string format) and decrypt using the information from the TextBox.

Please advice me on how to fix this problem.

[Here is the example of my concept, the first Textbox is where user input the encrypted data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zxcw.png)

Here is my code

```
    public static byte[] RSADecrypt2(byte[] ciphertext, string srcKey)
    {
        byte[] decryptedData;
        RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
        rsa.FromXmlString(srcKey);
        decryptedData = rsa.Decrypt(ciphertext, true);
        rsa.Dispose();
        return decryptedData;
    }

    private void RSADecrypt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        byte[] encryption = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(passBox.Text);
        string privateKey = rsaBoxPrivate.Text;
        byte[] decryption = RSADecrypt2(encryption, privateKey);
        decryptedBox.Text = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(decryption);
    }
```

Comment: RSA is not a block cipher, therefore it can be only used to encrypt a small amount of data (smaller than RSA key size). If you want to encrypt arbitrary data use a [hybrid encryption scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem) using RSA+AES.